# Is it unsafe to expose the user his own session ID?

Tags: security, session

I need to use a code in JavaScript to determine a user, I decided to use his session ID. Is it safe if I expose a user's session ID to himself?

Can he use the ID to hack a website sessions or change them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

He can see the session id anyway by examining the cookies (with cookies disabled it's usually even appended to every link as a GET argument).

So no, he cannot do anything evil with his **own** session id.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that PHP can trail a session id in the URL if user's cookies are disabled and if `session.use_only_cookies 1` and/or `session.use_trans_sid 0` are set.

Comment: That's what I meant with "with cookies disabled it's usually even appended to every link as a GET argument"

Comment: Default config usually doesn't append it in the absence of cookies, because users might bookmark / transmit links with session ids in them.

Comment: Ah, then it was changed - i think it used to be 1 by default

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there would be a major security issue by showing a user his own session id, since this id is generated per visit.  As long as that session id isn't given to someone it doesn't belong too, you should be good.